# How is it possible to link React-Native code with Swift or Kotlin? What should I do in each language?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, kotlin

I just started using expo for developing an app when I found out that apparently there are two different approaches into app development.

If I run:

```
expo init test
```

It prompts the following:

```
Choose a template: (Use arrow keys)
----- Managed workflow -----
❯ blank         minimal dependencies to run and an empty root component  
tabs          several example screens and tabs using react-navigation 
----- Bare workflow -----
bare-minimum  minimal setup for using unimodules
```

If I chose bare-minimum option, I get the following directories:

```sh
android  App.js  app.json  babel.config.js  index.js  ios  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  __tests__
```

So as if I chose blank I only get the following:

```sh
App.js  app.json  assets/  babel.config.js  node_modules/  package.json  package-lock.json
```

**What I know so far**: You can use React-Native, or Kotlin, or another language for different platforms.

**What I don't quite understand**: Apparently you can build your app with React-Native and get deeper access to platform resources with another language such as Kotlin, Java or Swift... Why is this necessary? Why you React-Native doesn't use full resources in the first instance? And finally, how react-native links with such a different languages?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `Expo`. Expo is a tool that assists React-native. If you want to use `Java` or `SWIFT` language, you must eject `Expo`. Create your own modules in `JAVA` or `SWIFT` and use them in `React Native`.

**useful links:**

1. [Expo eject(ExpoKit)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)
2. [Create Native Modules in ios](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios)
3. [Create Native Modules in android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)
4. [react-native link after Expo eject](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios)

Comment: @Slobish If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?